# Claims on signin in .NET Core RC2

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I'm porting a .NET 4.6 version to .NET Core RC2 and wondering how to do following in .NET Core RC2.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Firstname, this.Lastname)));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Organization", this.Organization.Name));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Role", manager.GetRoles(this.Id).FirstOrDefault()));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("ProfileImage", this.ProfileImageUrl));
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
}
```

and then a extension method for Identity.

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string FullName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("FullName");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string Organization(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Organization");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string Role(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Role");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string ProfileImage(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("ProfileImage");
        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Which gives me the result of using `User.Identity.ProfileImg();` etc..

Comment: i hope this gets answered, cause i'd like to know myself.

Comment: Ill provide an answer on how i solved it when i get back to my computer. @JeremyConterio

Comment: that would be awesome

Comment: @Rovdjuret did you make it back to your computer yet?

Comment: Haha, I'm embarassed as I forgot this, but you gave me a big laugh when I read this. I'll provide an answer with code example right away! @MichaelWheeler

Comment: @Rovdjuret I just wanted to make sure not happened to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for letting you guys wait!

I solved this by doing the following when creating a user. As in my case when the user is created I create claims which are stored as a relation to the user.
Then I keep these values updated through the whole process, which means each time someone changes the values they must be updated in the claims table aswell.

```
var user1 = new ApplicationUser()
{
    Firstname = "MyName",
    Lastname = "MyLastname",
    UserName = "name@domain.se",
    Email = "name@domain.se",
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    PhoneNumber = "000000000",
    OrganizationId = organization.Id,
    ProfileImageUrl = "user.jpg"
};
await userManager.CreateAsync(user1, "Qwerty1!");
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user1, "SuperAdmin");

var claims1 = new List<Claim> {
    new Claim("Email", user1.Email),
    new Claim("FullName", string.Format("{0} {1}", user1.Firstname, user1.Lastname)),
    new Claim("Organization", organization.Name),
    new Claim("Role", "SuperAdmin"),
    new Claim("ProfileImage", user1.ProfileImageUrl)
};

await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user1, claims1);
```

Last but not least I create the extension to get access to these for the current logged in user in views and controllers.

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Core.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityExtension
    {
        public static string FullName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("FullName");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public static string Organization(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Organization");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public static string Role(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Role");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public static string ProfileImage(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("ProfileImage");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public static string Email(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Email");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I can use is like this in my view for example

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Core.Extensions
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Overview";
}
<h4 class="mt-0 mb-5">Welcome back @User.Identity.FullName()</h4>
```