# How do I access my current user using IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4

I'm trying to build a SPA web app + IdentityServer4 + ASPNET Core + ASPNET Core Identity. I've followed the quickstarts on the Identityserver documentation and its really great. I'm more interested the quickstart [Identity Server Quickstart with JS Client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html)

I've followed it and so far so good. Now I've added some fields and related tables to my User, like so:

[image: app_user]

This is the Solution Explorer

[image: solution_explorer]

I would like to create a page that displays my user and its related tables/fields. (Basically, my question is, how do I access my current user and expose an API for my JS client to consume)

How do I achieve that? (All described points below I just read it online and I'm not sure how to implement it)

- Should I store my user in a session? Then access it from there?
- Should I use the connect/userinfo endpoint?

Please advise.

Comment: does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174121/get-property-of-applicationuser-from-the-asp-net-core-identity/39174256#39174256

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try. When using usermgr, will it go make calls to db every request? Or just once?

Comment: yes, it will get go to the db every request.  If you are performing the same query multiple times within the same request it hits it once, then pulls subsequent calls from cache.  (That also depends on the lifetime you have setup for in your dependency injection of the db context, but by default its setup for 'Scoped', or per request)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of `IdentityServer` is to separate concept of User Identity. In simple words, it means that your `web API` shouldn't/wouldn't have access to the database where users are stored.

Everything related to the user identity that is nessaccary in `web API` should be included in `access token` granted by `IdentityServer`. ( For example in claims)

In your example you can remove `Points` and `Wallets` fields from `ApplicaionUser` and create addition table for storing them, like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserSubject { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Wallet> Wallets { get; set; }
}
```

If you need something related to User Identity you can get it from claims like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
    ...
}
```

If you need `Points` and/or `Wallets` of a user, you can get `sub` claim from these claims and query your database for it.

It also means that you need to store `Points` and `Wallets` by user subject.

Comment: By `where users are stored`, does that mean, Users and Operational should be stored separately? Separate database? Oh, I see. So if I need additional data from a user like `Points` or `Wallets` (that doesn't have to do with user identity), I just use the `sub` claim and query the related record. Right?

Comment: @BoyPasmo yes, absolutely.

Comment: doesnt matter if it shoulda/woulda - app logic must have access to user identity. this is why identity server exists. not the other way around