# How can I change the value of ".GetUserName()" in the _LoginPartial view to a database field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need the value to change to a database field, it should show the name, but how do I do it?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + **User.Identity.GetUserId()** + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to see another value, not the email field, like a "Nombres" using my IdentityModels:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public int Rut { get; set; }
    public string Nombres { get; set; }
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public int Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public int Nacionalidad { get; set; }
```

User.Identity.GetUserId() shows the email, but I need it to show the "Nombres" data.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please edit your question, and paste the relevant code in. Adding code and/or error messages as images creates more work for those that are trying to help you, and some cases may put off those that could help you. Please see this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5508175) as to why you shouldn't post images of code/errors.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm a beginner on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to import Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin namespace into your view.Attach the below statement on top of your view.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```

Now you can get the value from OwinContext by invoking Usermanager context by firing FindMyName method on usermanager context which returns your ApplicationUser Object.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Nombres + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As per mvc pattern it is not a good idea to put application logic in view instead you can put application logic i.e getting the nombres field in controller action which returns a string and call Html.Action from your view

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

1. create a model with the property you need. ex : UserDisplayName

```
    class NavbarModel {
        public string UserDisplayName { get;set; }
    }
```

2. Bind your model in the HomeController Index action method.

```
    NavbarModel model = new NavbarModel();

    model.UserDisplayName = "some string";
```

3. Pass the model to the partial view
4. Inside the partial view you can access the property and display the value.

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + @Model.UserDisplayName  + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Please note this is just a workflow how you can implement the function.

Comment: I do not need to place a string, I need to place a field of my "identityModels", which is the user already logged into the system.

Comment: Can you please tell me what needs to show? If name of the user you can use User.Identity.Name

Comment: Edit the question again. Using IdentityModels, how do I show "Nombres" instead of email? thanks!

Comment: two ways. 1st one is @bhanu.cs 's answer. Or else you can put your properties as claims. Create an extension method to read the claims in views. call extension method in login partial. check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781423/how-should-i-access-my-applicationuser-properties-from-within-my-mvc-6-views